# How to get the name of the UIViewController that presented the custom AlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have implemented a custom alertview and the `delegate` methods are as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MyAlertViewController;

@protocol MyAlertViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void) alertViewControllerClickedPrimaryButton:(MyAlertViewController *)alertViewController;

@optional
-(void) alertViewControllerClickedSecondaryButton:(MyAlertViewController *)alertViewController;

@end
```

I have these delegate methods called in many view controllers.And Also I made one `SharedViewController` which I use it for all my `ViewControllers`

Lets say, one of these delegate method is called from `MasterViewController` which inherits `SharedViewController`,I will have this method in the `SharedViewController`:

```
#pragma mark My Alert Delegate
-(void) alertViewControllerClickedPrimaryButton:(MyAlertViewController *)alertViewController{

     //here how would I know that this alert is presented from MasterViewController ?

}
```

If I do `[self class]` , I would get the name as `SharedViewController`.

How can I get the name for my `MasterViewController` in my `SharedViewController`,when the `delegate` method is called from `MAsterVIewController`?

**Edit:** I added one parameter called `UIViewController` to the delegate method,and now it looks like this:

```
 -(void) alertViewControllerClickedSecondaryButton:(MyAlertViewController *)alertViewController :(UIViewController *)controllerName;
```

and what needs to send to delegate as controllerName?

I have this line to call the delegate method:

```
[_delegate alertViewControllerClickedSecondaryButton:self ]; //previous call
```

and I changed this to:

```
[_delegate alertViewControllerClickedSecondaryButton:self :<#(UIViewController *)#>]; // I have no idea which parameter to pass in here
```

any ideas?

Comment: What about adding another parameter that would include this information to your protocol method?

Comment: is it that simple? should it be a string or any class property?

Answer (score 0):

~  **EDIT**  ~

1. Select your storyboard file
2. Choose MasterViewController
3. In *Utilities* select **Identity Inspector**
4. Make sure the Class selected is `MasterViewController`
5. Just below the Custom Class area in the **Storyboard ID** textbox give it a custom name
6. Lastly, Tick the 'Use Storyboard ID' box √

   - ***Do the same for SharedViewController***
     *(and for any other VC's you have potentially presenting your alertviewcontroller)*

Now, in your Alert Delegate Method after your custom AlertVC has been presented onto the Navigation Stack:

```
-(void) alertViewControllerClickedPrimaryButton:(MyAlertController *)alertViewController 
{
/*  ... all other code
    ... 
    ... 
*/
    // Print the name of the Presenting View Controller
    NSLog(@"Presenting ViewController = %@", self.presentingViewController.restorationIdentifier);
}
```

Comment: alertViewController.presentingViewController
 is nil

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder?

Comment: @T_77 check my answer. I've edited it now knowing that you're using IB.

Comment: @T_77 any luck with finding a solution?